# MongoWire intro needed

Tags: mongodb, delphi, delphi-xe4

First time mongo/mongowire user...

Trying to get MongoWire demos to run, but it gives "No documents returned" error when I try to add a document with the included mwx1 demo. (Delphi XE4).

I can see in mongod console that connection is established.

Also, I manually created db "mwx1" and collection "items" with a document in mongo cli and if I 'refresh' the demo I can see my manually created docs, but cannot add a document from the demo code.

- Using Delphi XE4
- mongo 2.6.1
- mongowire version? (downloaded yesterday)

So I guess the question is how can I get the mongowire demo to work so I have a base to start learning, mongo+mongowire from.

Edit: FWIW if someone else hit this snag, edited mongoWire.pas from line 391

```
if p.NumberReturned=0
      then raise EMongoQueryError.Create('MongoWire.Get: no documents returned');
```

to

```
if p.NumberReturned=0
   then begin;
         FWriteLock.Leave;
         Result:=nil;
         exit;
        end;
```

Also TMongowire.Runcommand line 532:

```
if (Result<>nil) and (Result['ok']<>1) then
```

And it's working correctly as far I can tell.

Comment: If you have an answer to your own question, feel free to post it as an answer and accept it, not only for your reputation counter but also for later readers and to reduce open questions :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with the NameSpace and Collection naming. Please get the new version I just pushed from https://github.com/stijnsanders/TMongoWire